# Leak under the sink?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, leak, sink

I had a guest in the basement. The cleaning lady came to clean after the guest left. I asked the cleaning lady if everything is ok or if there any damages.
The cleaning lady suspected a leak under the sink. I looked the floor was wet but the pipes were dry. I dried out the floor and the interior of the underneath cabinet then turned on the water for a minute. I did not see a leak. The area was dry. The pipes from top till the end were dry. I checked back in 30 minutes and it was still dry. I tried the same test again and again no leakage noted.
I don’t want to call for a plumber for a wrong suspicion that someone else made.
How long should the water run to test for any leak?
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: What part of the floor was wet? Under the sink? In front of the sink? Is the sink in a cabinet?

Comment: Sounds like the guess might spill something by accident.  Usually a plumbing leak will show at least a drop or two on the pipe.  Keep an eye on it every few days or every day for a bit.

Comment: The pipes under the sink are in a cabinet. So the bottom of the cabinet and the interior side walls  were wet. There was a little bit of water in front of the sink. When I tested twice I did not see any water. I had the water one for no longer than a minute. Thank you

Comment: The water in the inlet pipes is under pressure all the time, so a leak will be there if running the water or not.  It is possible that it is leaking from the drain pipe, so fill up(half full) the sink before draining and check underneath when the water drains.

Comment: could be water on the countertop leaks between it and the sink.  is this undermount or surface mount?

Comment: Why not ask the guest what happened?

Comment: It was a surface amount. I tested it again this morning and no leak so I am not going to call a plumber for now.

Answer (score 1):

Leak or not leak, that is the question.

The crime scene:

Evidance of a crime was found.

Wet floor. What caused it and it is no longer there?

Sink got clogged and the mysterious visitor panicked from the wrath of the home owner.

Visitor took action to unclog the sink. Unscrewed the drain (only hand tied). Removed the the pipe and unclogged it while spilled water in the process.

=================================================

I use this leak sensors to make me sleep, without worries.

It will even inform you on your phone when you are not at home.

I placed sensors at each possible location. Under sink, next to washing machine, next to dishwasher

[image]